# (dis)advantages of using bridges & transports where not strictly needed?

Tags: anonymity, bridge, pluggable-transports

What if any are the (dis)advantages - with respect to speed, anonymity, secrecy... - in using bridges and obfuscated transports from such places where access to plain Tor relays is *NOT* blocked nor forbidden ? 
Unrelated to that other question (#13575), I'm asking here for a comparison of using bridges (and optionally obfuscated transports) wrt connecting to a regular entry relay, *i.e.* not a bridge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are security implications of keeping same tor bridges versus rotating?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/what-are-security-implications-of-keeping-same-tor-bridges-versus-rotating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an advantage can be the lesser detectability of your connection/session. Disadvantage is that you must encomplicate the relay descriptor to flag the relay "as the one using obfuscation" and which one. It's a good research line, but in a plain context it's hardly useful

Comment: I would think more processing power used (maybe wasted) as a disadvantage of using transports. Also, aren't bridges a limited resource that using without a need would be a net waste ?

Comment: bridges are semi-useful in cases when you can work without them, but some specific cases may require their usage even in such a cases. CPU power is not wasted in case of pluggable transports: everything has it's resource costs, including privacy increase provided by pluggable transports

Comment: I don't think bridges are a limited resource. Due to the nature of bridges, many of them probably don't see much traffic. I don't believe it would be a net waste, but you might have a slower connection since bridges often have less bandwidth than guards.